# How do I get the max value in this example?

Tags: java, arrays, generics, extends, comparable

For example this is how I would get the max here

```
public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T x, T y, T z) {
        T max = values;
        if (y.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = y;
        }
        
        if (z.compareTo(max) > 0) {
            max = z;
        }
        return max;

    }
```

How would I get the max here?

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T... values) {
        T max = values;
        if(
        return max;
    }
```

This is what i tried, but i got this error: Arrays.java:21:
error: bad operand types for binary operator '>'

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <T extends Comparable<T>> T max(T... values) {
        T max = values[0];
        for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
            if (values[i].compareTo(max) > max) {
                max = values[i];
            }
        }
        
        return max;
    }
```

Comment: `if (values[i].compareTo(max) > 0)`

Comment: omg! it was that easy. Thank you.